# Get specific places on a map from CoreLocation

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, location, core-location

Is there a way to determine specific places that users are currently in? I would like to show more than the current city or country they are in and instead show lakes, parks, and other things that if searched on a map would correspond to that location (i.e. Sears Tower, Downtown New York, Yellowstone Park). Also, if this is not possible can anyone provide an example showing the updated way of getting which city you are in? Im using Obj-c in Xcode, but I am having trouble doing this. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code I'm using so far:

Implementaion

```
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

ViewDidLoad

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

Button

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Void Method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:  (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", currentLocation);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the coordinates you receive from LocationManager to CLGeocoder

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];    
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:
    ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
           CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
           NSLog(@"country is: %@", placemark.country );
        }
    }];
```